# ASP MVC - calling a controller with a list in the parameter model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to transfer a string aray in my url to a mvc controller .

My controller method is

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
```

and I want My model to be

```
public class TagEditRequestVM
{
    public string ValueA { get; set; }

    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

what is the best url structure to call it?

Comment: Look here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an index and the []-notation:

```
http://host/Controller/Index?ValueA=val&MyList[0]=item1&MyList[1]=item2
```

THe index hasn't to be an incrementing integer - it just has to be unique.

**EDIT**

Ok, thanks to the link plurby writes in his comment you can leave out the bracket notation and just repeat the property name:

```
http://host/Controller/Index?ValueA=val&MyList=item1&MyList=item2
```